# Celebrate request validation failed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, joi

I'm getting this weird error whenever I try to post something on my site. It is a field where the user can enter text or enter a media file such as photo or video. But when I try to enter text this error is returned.So I just can't post anything text or image.

```
{statusCode: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "celebrate request validation failed",…}
error: "Bad Request"
message: "celebrate request validation failed"
statusCode: 400
validation: {body: {source: "body", keys: ["file"], message: ""file" is not allowed"}}
body: {source: "body", keys: ["file"], message: ""file" is not allowed"}
keys: ["file"]
message: "\"file\" is not allowed"
source: "body"
```

My Front End is built with React.

```
const handleStoryCreate = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      const data = {
        text: inputValue,
      };

      const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        text: Yup.string().required('Texto obrigatório'),
      });

      await schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false });

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('text', data.text);
      formData.append('file', fileImage);

      await api.post('stories', formData, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
        },
      });
```

Here the route:

```
router.post(
  '/',
  ensureAuthorization('user'),
  ensureFiles('file', false),
  resize,
  celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: {
      text: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  }),
  storiesController.create,
);
```

Comment: await api.post('/stories', formData, => (frontend)

`
router.post(
  '/stories',
  ensureAuthorization('user'),
  ensureFiles('file', false),
  resize,
  celebrate({
    [Segments.BODY]: {
      text: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  }),
  storiesController.create,
);
` => backend

Comment: @adhinarayan I couldn't understand what you meant?